# What are good investments to use as hedges when the Federal Reserve draws down quantitative easing?

Tags: investing, economics, inflation, monetary-policy, federal-reserve

Basically I think it is quite obvious that quantitative easing (QE) will be pulled back eventually and countries will start to tighten their monetary policy. When that happens, what kind of assets will be able to hold their value, and hopefully appreciate?

I know commodities are a good inflation hedge, however when QEs are gone, I think what will happen is disinflation (reduced inflation). Things like collectible items may be good, but they are beyond the reach of a normal investor.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Since the adoption of the [Evans Rule](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2012-12-12/the-fed-gets-aggressively-dovish), the Federal Reserve has signaled that they probably won't pull back QE until inflation surpasses 2.5%, which is well above the current target (2%). This makes me *extremely* skeptical that the pullback of QE and the accompanying rise in interest rates will lead to deflation because the rate of inflation would need to drop over *two points*, which is huge.

Comment: I should clarify that the draw down of QE might lead to *reduced inflation* (down from the 2.5% threshold), but reduced inflation is not equivalent to deflation. Also, merely because the US central bank draws down QE doesn't mean other countries will tighten their monetary policies either. Besides, there are many countries that aren't using QE-style monetary policy now, so they don't have a QE policy to draw down.

Comment: Re: *"reduced inflation is not equivalent to deflation"* .. the term you might be looking for is ["disinflation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinflation).

Comment: @JohnBensin Sorry, disinflation should be the right term, I have made corrections to the question.

Comment: @AZhu Disinflation isn't necessarily a problem. If the economy were to enter a disinflationary period, it could be because of unemployment above the natural growth rate, which isn't ideal, but that's only a possibility. If the Fed draws down QE when the economy is above the Evans threshold, and this leads to a decrease in the growth rate of inflation (disinflation), this isn't really a problem. Inflation may decrease to near the inflation target, which is actually positive. In this case, no hedge is necessary because the economy is functioning normally.

Comment: @AZhu Also, keep in mind that disinflation isn't the same as low inflation either. Disinflation refers to the *change* in the *growth of inflation.* Inflation is like the speed of your car, while disinflation is like the acceleration. Just as it's possible to slow down when you're traveling quickly, it's possible to have disinflation in a high inflationary period. (Inflation is the 1st derivative of prices; disinflation is one instance of the 2nd derivative). The presence of disinflation may indicate different economic scenarios, but it doesn't necessitate a special hedge.

Comment: @AZhu Long story short, the draw down of QE isn't the disaster scenario that the comment on the original quant.SE question is predicting. Although some people worry about this, it's important to take a step back any time you hear a prediction of disaster like that. Someone is always predicting disaster, *all the time,* but the economy is still here and the business cycle continues.

Comment: Also, this question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for specific investment advice.

Comment: @JohnBensin WRT to "specific investment advice", that part might be corrected if the OP were asking about asset classes (more general) as opposed to investments (more specific).

Answer (score 1):

Take defensive positions that will protect you from the scenario you anticipate,

- short emerging markets (EM)
- buy fixed income securities that will protect you from your expected changes in the shape of the yield curve
- buy US Dollar currency futures, forward contracts, or options on futures

For example, go long USD/THB where THB = Thai Baht. THB is one of the few convertible currencies among emerging markets. There are a few forex brokers who will do this  transaction. The cost of the trade is likely to be high though.

In your scenario, the US dollar will be king, eventually ... even if, ultimately, only temporarily :)